# def max_num(num1, num2, num3): if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3: return num1 elif num2 >= num1 an

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Peace be upon you. I am facing a problem with this code in the Python language. Is it possible that there is a mistake in the code because I apply it with the course and the same code in the course comes up, and I have a problem, can you help me with this code

```
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
          
          return num1
       elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
           return num2
           else:
               return num3
      
print(max_num(50, 265, 10))
```

Comment: You need to explain the problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

You have an indentation issue. This way works:

```py
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
        return num1
    elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
        return num2
    else:
        return num3

print(max_num(50, 265, 10))
```

See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [Lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) for more details.

Comment: hello I'm have the same issue on new code

Comment: This is the code

Comment: 'num1 = float(input("please enter the first number: "))
operator = input("please enter the operator: ")
num2 = float(input("please enter the second number: "))

if operator == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif operator == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif operator == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
 elif operator == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
else:
    print("worg oprator plase try agin")'

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.